# Change MainPage in Xamarin.Forms based on Run-Time Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Visual Studio Xamarin Forms project, I created a new run-time configuration (*AppName.ios - DevBuild*). I now have two configurations, one is the default (*AppName.iOS*) and another one is the Custom Configuration (*AppName.iOS - DevBuild*). Based on the run-time configuration, I want to display a page. How do I do that?

For example: Let us take two pages named *Page A* and *Page B*. If the project is built using *AppName.iOS-DevBuild*, then *Page A* should be the `MainPage`. If not, then *Page B* should be the `MainPage`.

Comment: What is two  run time configuration? Are there two info.plists in your iOS project?

Comment: you can define compiler flags on a per-config basis, and use #IFDEF checks in your code to conditionally execute based on those flags

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : No, there is just one info.plists

Comment: @Jason : is there any example you can share ??

Comment: I still don't know how do you config your Run-Time Configuration? Show us some relevant code? Or you want a way to do Run-Time Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

in the project options dialog, under Compiler, in the "Define Symbols" box, add a symbol "MySymbolName".  This can be done per-configuration

then in your code

```
#if MySymbolName
  // any code in this block will only be compiled in configurations where
  // MySymbolName is defined
#endif
```

Comment: Should i declare it in shared project or else in Android and iOS project ??

Comment: in the project where you intend to use it

Comment: Tried it not working. This is what i did, in the Android Project i defined a new configuration and defined a symbol. But when i choose my configuration and run it is showing same old page instead of the new page